# Python unicode write to file crashes in command line but not in IDE

Tags: python, unicode, aptana, pydev

I'm having a problem wherein my Python 2.7.3rc2 code runs fine through an IDE (Aptana Studio 3 with PyDev), but crashes when I either double-click the .py file or try to run it from the Windows command line.

The problem line is where I try to write a string containing unicode characters to a file. The IDE has no problem with it, and writes the file properly with the unicode characters. The command line version complains that it can't encode certain characters.

The root of the question is: what's different about the IDE version versus the command line version that one writes a unicode file properly and the other does not?

The ideal solution should have the command line version working exactly as the IDE version does.

---

**EDIT:** Sorry, I thought it was assumed which command I was using to write a string to a file, but I'm new to Python. The actual command is `write()` called on an object `f` which was instantiated with `f = open(path, 'w')`. I pass it the string I want it to write to the file, and that string contains unicode characters.

The full error message is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "writer.py", line 46, in <module>
    write_listings(c, output_path)
  File "writer.py", line 33, in write_listings
    print name
  File "c:\Python27\lib\encodings\cp437.py", line 12, in encode
    return codecs.charmap_encode(input,errors,encoding_map)
UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode characters in position 21-26: character maps to <undefined>
```

Here is an example string:
`滑鐵盧安大略加拿大`

Unfortunately I'm having trouble creating an SSCCE because I can't just put that string literal into a source code file without it complaining that I haven't declared an encoding. It's frustrating -- this was all working so well when I ran everything from the IDE and now I'm headed down a unicode rabbit hole!

**EDIT**: Thanks to Fredrik, I'm now able to make an SSCCE. Here it is:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
str = u'滑鐵盧安大略加拿大'
f = open('test', 'w')
f.write(str)
f.close()
```

This SSCCE crashes when run from command line but *not* from the IDE. **Why is that?**

**EDIT**: I added some additional code suggested by Edward Loper to verify that the version of Python is identical for the command line and IDE versions.

Here is the new code:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import sys
print sys.version
print open
print open.__module__

str = u'滑鐵盧安大略加拿大'
f = open('test', 'w')
f.write(str)
f.close()
```

Here is the output when run from the IDE:

```
2.7.3rc2 (default, Mar 18 2012, 22:59:27) [MSC v.1500 64 bit (AMD64)]
<built-in function open>
__builtin__
```

And here is the output when run from the command line:

```
2.7.3rc2 (default, Mar 18 2012, 22:59:27) [MSC v.1500 64 bit (AMD64)]
<built-in function open>
__builtin__
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 9, in <module>
    f.write(str)
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode characters in position 0-8: ordinal not in range(128)
```

In my opinion, the question is still unanswered because I still have no idea what would make it work in the IDE and not the command line!

Comment: [http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0263/](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0263/)? add `# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-` to top of file

Comment: Is it just a file or are you also writing anything with Unicode characters to console? Console in IDE usually uses different encoding than Windows console does.

Comment: Not very helpful. What was the command that gave the error? And what error message was reported?

Comment: @Fenikso I wasn't trying to print anything out to the console. When I do try to print the string in question, I get a similar `UnicodeEncodeError`.

Comment: @aitchnyu Sorry, I thought it was clear which command I was using to write a string to a file. I've clarified in the edit.

Comment: Sorry, but there is probably no way how we can help if you do not show us the string in question and the code which writes it no problem by IDE and crashes in Windows console. Stripped down runnable two-line code would be great.

Comment: @Fredrik Thanks, now I can make an SSCCE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Fenikso said, you should encode a string before writing it to a file.  The reason that file.write() doesn't do this itself is that you need to specify which encoding (utf-8, utf-16, etc) you want to use.  There's a python module "codecs" which allows you to create stream objects that know what encoding to use, and automatically apply it.  That's what Fenikso is using in his second example.

As to why your code works in the IDE but not the command line, my guess is that your IDE is setting the "default encoding" to some non-default value.  Try running this in both the IDE and the command line and see if it differs:

```
>>> import sys
>>> print sys.getdefaultencoding()
```

Here's some related information: http://blog.ianbicking.org/illusive-setdefaultencoding.html

Comment: I will edit my question above to show the output from my SSCCE with your additional commands. Spoiler alert -- it's identical except for the error.

Comment: (I modified the second part of my answer when I thought of the possibility that this might have to do w/ default encodings)

Comment: Yep, this is the ticket! `sys.getdefaultencoding()` is `ascii` for the command line and `utf-8` for the IDE. Although I don't really have any idea about all these `site.py` and `sitecustomize.py` files on my drive, there's definitely some customization going on in the IDE that makes it different from the console and that's what's causing the problem. Thanks so much for going the distance and getting to the root of the problem!

Answer (score 3):

You should explicitly encode your string in desired encoding before writing it in the file:

```
f.write(text.encode("cp1250", "replace")) # Czech Windows encoding, use your own
```

or

```
f.write(text.encode("utf-8", "replace")) # UTF-8
```

You can also explicitly open the file with specific encoding:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from __future__ import unicode_literals
import codecs

x = "abcč"
f = codecs.open("test.txt", "w", "utf-8", "replace")
f.write(x)
```

Comment: So the good news is that this fixes the problem. The bad news is that I still have no idea why this works through an IDE but not in the command line? Does everybody explicitly encode text when writing to a file? If so, why doesn't f.write() do it itself?

Comment: IDE console is different than your system console and probably uses different encoding. Python tries to implicitly encode your string and picks "wrong" encoding (in my case "ascii") for system console but the right one for Eclipse console ("utf-8" in my case).

Comment: I have updated my answer with a way how to open file with specified encoding.

Comment: But I'm not printing the string -- I'm just writing it directly to a file. Why does the console encoding matter? I agree that if I tried to print it there would be a problem, but why can I write to a file successfully through the IDE and not the console?

Comment: I guess that opening file picks default encoding based on the console settings. Try printing `print sys.getdefaultencoding()` in both.

Answer (score 1):

This is how I do whenever I need to work with a specific encoding

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: UTF-8 -*-
import codecs
out = codecs.getwriter('utf-8')(sys.stdout)
out.write('some åäö-string')
```

Comment: This seems like another good approach, very similar to Fenikso's answer above. Again, this would likely solve the crash but doesn't answer why this code change is necessary in console vs. IDE execution. It seems there must be some environment variable set by the IDE that defines a default encoding of UTF-8 or something when writing to a file, whereas when running from the console it assumes ASCII? Is that possible?