# Can't run Python 'Hello World' in Komodo

Tags: python-2.7, komodo

I have Python 2.7.2 (64 bit) and Komodo IDE 7.0.

When I try to run Hello World or a sample or an empty file in Komodo I get the following error:

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xd1 in position 277: ordinal not in range(128)
```

Comment: Did you write the 'Hello World' yourself?

Answer (score 0):

Use the [Komodo status bar](http://docs.activestate.com/komodo/7.0/workspace.html#Status_Bar) or [the python source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9822655/python-unicode-write-to-file-crashes-in-command-line-but-not-in-ide) to specify a character encoding other than the default, ASCII.

Answer (score 0):

Is your ActiveState Komodo installation a brand-new one ?

I have experienced this kind of error message with Komodo 8.5.In my case, the problem was

- some time ago, this installation was used with programs written in Polish characters
  Windows-1250 coding and the same coding was used in the names of folders
- recently, I switched to use UTF-8 in all my programs and not to use polish-specific characters in paths
- Komodo remembered old breakpoints, EVEN the scripts and their paths did not exist anymore
- Komodo failed while starting ANY new script, trying to restore old breakpoints
  of old, non-existing scripts.

The remedium was very simple - delete old brekpoints.